# Do we need to install any kind of driver when using a Vertex SSD drive?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, vertex-3

I've put a Vertex SSD driver in my laptop. I've successfully installed Windows on top of it and all, but I'd like to know if I'm expected to install extra drivers or not. I've googled a bit and at least at first, that doesn't seem to be the case, but I'd like to be sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Solid state drives are supposed to be no different than any other storage device.  The only drivers necessary should be for the storage controller, in this case your SATA controller.  A drive is a drive is a drive, basically.

(There may be some really oddball products out there that don't follow this rule, but I don't recall the last time I've seen one.)